# Zend Framework 2. ZfcUser. Authentication error with right email/pass when i added new element in login form

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication, zfcuser

I got authentication error with right email/pass of registered user when i added new element in login form in ZfcUser.

I added new element in bootstrap function with this lines:

```
<?php

namespace SystemUser;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $events = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    $sharedEvents->attach('ZfcUser\Form\Login',
        'init',
        function($e)
        {
            // @var $form \ZfcUser\Form\Login
            $form = $e->getTarget();

            // Configure email input
            $form->get('identity')
                ->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Your email')
                ->setAttribute('class', 'text-input')
                ->setAttribute('title', 'Your email');

            // Configure password input
            $form->get('credential')
                ->setAttribute('placeholder', 'Your password')
                ->setAttribute('class', 'text-input')
                ->setAttribute('title', 'Your password');

            // Configure submit button
            $form->get('submit')
                ->setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary submit');

            // Add field "Keep me signed in."
            $form->add(
                array(
                    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox',
                    'name' => 'keep_signed_in',
                    'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'Keep me signed in.',
                        'use_hidden_Element' => true,
                        'checked_value' => '1',
                        'unchecked_value' => '0'
                    ),
                    'attributes' => array(
                        'id' => 'keep_signed_in',
                    ),
                )
            );

        }
    );

}
```

But with new element 'keep_signed_in' login form allways returns error "Authentication failed. Please try again."

Please help. What I must to do for dropping this error with real auth params?

Thank you, guys!

Comment: If you are getting an auth error, then likely there is an issue with the script doing the logging in. Is that in the PHP script that you are hiding from us?

Comment: I don't hide code from anybody. When I deleted code $form->add( ... ) authentication is started to work well. But I need this checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out solution! :)

I forgot specify filter for this checkbox with required=false:

```
$sharedEvents->attach('ZfcUser\Form\LoginFilter', 'init', function($e) {
        // @var $form \ZfcUser\Form\LoginFilter
        $filter = $e->getTarget();

        // Custom field keep_signed_in
        $filter->add(array(
                'name'       => 'keep_signed_in',
                'required'   => false,
            )
        );

    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to do something which another module is already doing: https://github.com/goalio/GoalioRememberMe (i know that's not the answer to your question, but now you might not need an answer :))

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. I will try this, if don't find out solution of the topic.